# calling Valums Ajax uploader from other DOM element

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm facing a problem with the valums Ajax File upload.

Since the plugin is working perfectly after a few modifications on the server side, I cannot implement a specific behavior.

My DOM is composed with an input file plus the container to instantiate the fileuploader buttons.

What I want is to be able to fire the fileuploader plugins when clicking on the input:file[name="upload-file"].

```
...
<div id="upload-accepted">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="upload-file">Select a file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="upload-file" id="upload-file"/>
    <noscript>
      <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
    </noscript>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="upload-container">
  </div>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
      action: '/file-upload',
      element: document.getElementById('upload-container'),
      onSubmit: function(id, filename){...},
      onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){...}
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have tried to add the following on the script but it don't works

```
$("#upload-file").live('change', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.qq-upload-button').trigger('click');
  return false;
});
```

Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a live demo?  No need to give access to the actual upload but i need to see what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger this :

`$('input[name="file"]').trigger('click');`

It works for me !

Comment: Worked perfect for me too!

Answer (score 0):

When setting up a FileUploader you specify option element, usually something like this:

```
new qq.FileUploader({
   element: document.getElementById('uploadImage'),
...
```

If you check DOM script inserts upload input inside div with this id. So you should be able to access input and link click action to it.

If you are using jQuery it should work something like this:

```
$('#uploadImage input').trigger('click');
```

or simply

```
$('#uploadImage input').click();
```